# Difference between 'where should' and 'where do'

Tags: differences

What is the difference between "where do I eat?" and "where should I eat?" ?

Comment: Please consult a dictionary about the difference between [should](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/should?q=should) and [do](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/do?q=do). If that is not sufficient please edit your question to explain what the confusion is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe in this sense that

> Where do I eat?

is asking for a single definite place to eat

in contrast to

> Where should I eat?

which is asking for opinions on multiple places where you should eat.

Both seem fine to me though but I think the latter is more commonly utilised.

Comment: OP hasn't provided any context, so we can't tell whether there's any expectation of the questioner's part that there may actually only be *one place possible*. For example, he may be visiting an isolated company's office where the only place he could feasibly reach during a short lunch break is the office canteen on the premises. Even then, both versions would be acceptable, but *"do"* might feel more "natural" to some speakers.